# EJB-QL Query List inside Object

Tags: java, hql, ejbql

I'm attempting to write what should be a simple (I hope) EJB-QL query.

Here are my objects:

```
public class Room {
     private String name;
     private List<RoomConfiguration> configs;
}

public class RoomConfiguration {
     private Integer capacity;
     private String name;
}
```

How can I search for rooms with a minimum capacity?  A room can have multiple configurations, and each of those configurations has a different capacity.

Comment: Is Room.name = RoomConfiguration.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select room, config 
from Room room 
left outer join room.configs config
where config.capacity = (select min(rc.capacity) from RoomConfiguration rc)
```